# Creating and releasing ZIP folder of a part of my GitHub repo

Tags: github, github-actions

I asked this question before, but I decided to delete it and re-create it as it was quite bad, and I think I got a lot of progress on it.
I'm very very new to github, and i've been trying to get github to make a zip of my repo without creating another folder in the zip file. On a normal download of the code as ZIP, github will give me `folder.zip/folder/files`, but i need it to give me `folder.zip/files`.

I've been looking at tutorials and trying to create a Github Action that does this for me, but i'm a bit stuck on what to put in a line.
This is my code currently:

```yaml
name: Create Archive
on: 
  push:
    tags:
    - '*'
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Archive Release
      uses: thedoctor0/zip-release@0.7.1
      with:
        type: 'zip'
        filename: 'folder.zip'
        exclusions: '*.git* /*node_modules/* .editorconfig'
  notify:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:  
      - uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1.13.0
        with:
          artifacts: "folder.zip"
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

In the line that says "artifacts: folder.zip", i have absolutely no idea what i'm supposed to do. the github repo for release-action doesn't help as i can't understand the directions, and looking up how to use artifacts doesn't really help me either.
When i run this Action, this is what i get:
`Artifact pattern :modpack.zip did not match any files`.

What i want it to do, is to create a release whenever i push a new tag which includes a download to the ZIP folder im trying to make. This doesn't happen, as the release only includes the download for the source code.